# Как перебрать все файлы .csv из папки и получить корреляции между файлами?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Хочу взять все файлы .csv из папки и прогнать в этом коде, получив корреляции между файлами.

Как правильно исправить: `(symbols_list = Path(r'C:/Data'))`?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn

start = datetime(2019, 1, 1)
symbols_list = ['AAPL', 'F', 'TWTR', 'FB', 'AAL', 'AMZN', 'GOOGL', 'GE']

symbols=[]

for ticker in symbols_list: 
    r = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start)
    r['Symbol'] = ticker 
    symbols.append(r)

df = pd.concat(symbols)
df = df.reset_index()
df = df[['Date', 'Close', 'Symbol']]

df_pivot = df.pivot('Date','Symbol','Close').reset_index()

corr_df = df_pivot.corr(method='pearson')

corr_df.head().reset_index()
del corr_df.index.name
corr_df
```

Это полностью рабочий код, на выходе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Входные данные: https://dropmefiles.com/aXaex

```
Date    Adj Close   Close   High    Low Open    Volume
1/2/2018    166.353714  172.2599945 172.3000031 169.2599945 170.1600037 25555900
1/3/2018    166.3247223 172.2299957 174.5500031 171.9600067 172.5299988 29517900
1/4/2018    167.09729   173.0299988 173.4700012 172.0800018 172.5399933 22434600
1/8/2018    168.3720398 174.3500061 175.6100006 173.9299927 174.3500061 20567800
1/9/2018    168.3527222 174.3300018 175.0599976 173.4100037 174.5500031 21584000
```

Comment: Можете уточнить - в чем суть вопроса?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если суть вопроса в том, чтобы изменить данный код так, чтобы данные читались из CSV файлов из одной директории, то сделать это можно так:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

p = Path(r"D:\download\.data")  

df = (pd
      .concat(
        [pd.read_csv(f, usecols=["Date", "Close"]).assign(Symbol=f.stem)
         for f in p.glob("*.csv")],
        ignore_index=True)
      .pivot(index="Date", columns="Symbol", values="Close"))

corr_df = df.corr(method='pearson')

pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.4f}'.format
print(corr_df)
```

---

результат:

```
Symbol    ABBV     ABC     ABT    ACAD     ACC    ACGL    ACHC    ACIW     ACM     ACN    ADBE     ADI     ADM
Symbol
ABBV    1.0000  0.5517 -0.8029 -0.2716 -0.8211 -0.6080  0.6024 -0.6606  0.0566 -0.5522 -0.6880 -0.6088  0.4409
ABC     0.5517  1.0000 -0.3774  0.0644 -0.4869 -0.1198  0.4358 -0.4539  0.4234 -0.0658 -0.3704 -0.2713  0.1779
ABT    -0.8029 -0.3774  1.0000  0.6249  0.8910  0.8594 -0.6313  0.8973  0.2932  0.8414  0.8717  0.8102 -0.4257
ACAD   -0.2716  0.0644  0.6249  1.0000  0.5182  0.8295 -0.4231  0.5657  0.7552  0.7104  0.4519  0.6118 -0.4653
ACC    -0.8211 -0.4869  0.8910  0.5182  1.0000  0.7766 -0.6057  0.8677  0.1999  0.7411  0.8115  0.8170 -0.4128
ACGL   -0.6080 -0.1198  0.8594  0.8295  0.7766  1.0000 -0.4870  0.7538  0.6534  0.9227  0.7608  0.8356 -0.4874
ACHC    0.6024  0.4358 -0.6313 -0.4231 -0.6057 -0.4870  1.0000 -0.5157  0.0623 -0.3139 -0.3024 -0.3900  0.6086
ACIW   -0.6606 -0.4539  0.8973  0.5657  0.8677  0.7538 -0.5157  1.0000  0.2894  0.7745  0.8688  0.8297 -0.2516
ACM     0.0566  0.4234  0.2932  0.7552  0.1999  0.6534  0.0623  0.2894  1.0000  0.6292  0.3171  0.4927 -0.1822
ACN    -0.5522 -0.0658  0.8414  0.7104  0.7411  0.9227 -0.3139  0.7745  0.6292  1.0000  0.8545  0.8457 -0.3193
ADBE   -0.6880 -0.3704  0.8717  0.4519  0.8115  0.7608 -0.3024  0.8688  0.3171  0.8545  1.0000  0.8170 -0.1243
ADI    -0.6088 -0.2713  0.8102  0.6118  0.8170  0.8356 -0.3900  0.8297  0.4927  0.8457  0.8170  1.0000 -0.4116
ADM     0.4409  0.1779 -0.4257 -0.4653 -0.4128 -0.4874  0.6086 -0.2516 -0.1822 -0.3193 -0.1243 -0.4116  1.0000
```